# JQuery append text to current tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, traversal

I have dynamic code which creates tabs based on how many results are returned.  My issue is now, I want to append a tick to the tab title but I can't traverse to the `<li>` and `<a href`> I need to append the tick to (append to the `<a href>`).  I've tried lots of `.parent()` and `.find()` but I just can't seem to get this correct.  What am I missing (and no doubt it's simple!)

```
function getData() {
$.getJSON("getQuestions.asp?sup="+dataVal1+"&prod="+dataVal2, function(data){})
    .done(function(data){               
        html = '<div class="center">Supplier: '+suppName+'</div><div class="center">'
        html += 'Part No &amp; Description: '+partCode+' - '+partName+'</div><ul>'
        var len = data.length;  
        for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
            html += '<li><a href="#q'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].shortdesc+'</a></li>'
        }
        html += '</ul>'
        for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
            html += '<div id="q'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].question
            html += '<fieldset><legend>Question '+parseInt(i+1)+'</legend>'
            if (data[i].evidence == '1') {
                html += '<iframe id="upload" frameborder="0" width="500" scrolling="no" src="upload.asp?supp='+suppCode+'&part='+partCode+'&q='+data[i].shortdesc+'"></iframe>'
                console.log(data[i].shortdesc)
            } else {
                html += '<div class="yesno" data-desc="'+data[i].shortdesc+'"><span class="btn small" id="yes" >YES</span>&nbsp;<span class="btn small" id="no">NO</span></div>'
            }
            html +='</fieldset></div>'
        }

        $('#output').html(html);
        $( "#output" ).tabs();
    }); 
};
```

I have searched thoroughly for this and it may be possible I've not hit the exact solution which may be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tabs events to do that. There you have access to find the anchor tag.

```
    function getData() {
$.getJSON("getQuestions.asp?sup="+dataVal1+"&prod="+dataVal2, function(data){})
    .done(function(data){               
        html = '<div class="center">Supplier: '+suppName+'</div><div class="center">'
        html += 'Part No &amp; Description: '+partCode+' - '+partName+'</div><ul>'
        var len = data.length;  
        for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
            html += '<li><a id="tab_"'+ i +' href="#q'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].shortdesc+'</a></li>'
        }
        html += '</ul>'
        for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
            html += '<div id="q'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].question
            html += '<fieldset><legend>Question '+parseInt(i+1)+'</legend>'
            if (data[i].evidence == '1') {
                html += '<iframe id="upload" frameborder="0" width="500" scrolling="no" src="upload.asp?supp='+suppCode+'&part='+partCode+'&q='+data[i].shortdesc+'"></iframe>'
                console.log(data[i].shortdesc)
            } else {
                html += '<div class="yesno" data-desc="'+data[i].shortdesc+'"><span class="btn small" id="yes" >YES</span>&nbsp;<span class="btn small" id="no">NO</span></div>'
            }
            html +='</fieldset></div>'
        }

        $('#output').html(html);
        $( "#output" ).tabs();
    }); 
};

    $( "#output" ).tabs({
                activate : function(event, ui){

                    var tab_index = ui.newTab.index();
                    var anchor_tag = ui.newTab.children("a");
                    var anchor_tag_id = anchor_tag.attr("id");

                    localStorage.setItem("active_tab_anchor", anchor_tag_id);
                }
    });

    $('#answer_event').on('click', function(){
            var anchor_tag_id = localStorage.getItem("active_tab_anchor");
        var anchor_tag = $('#'+anchor_tag_id);
        var href = anchor_tag.attr("href");
        href += href + 'tick';
        anchor_tag.attr('href', href);
    });
```

It depends when exactly you want to append the tick.

Check the events here: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: This is where I should expand my original question.  Within each tab is a "question" which when answered, should then mark that tab with a tick

Comment: ok, let's think this through. I would say, when you click the tab it means you can set a local storage variable with the active tab id, if the user answer the question then you look for that specific tab with the id and try to find the anchor tag related to it.

Comment: When you create the anchor tag per tab, try to add an id to it, then in the activate event try to save that anchor tag id in the local storage. If the user answer the question then you can find the anchor tag really easy by the id you saved in the local storage and modify the href.

Comment: Thanks @dquinonez, currently working down the route of getting the `<a href id=''>` to refer back to, I have the tab link ID now, it's just find a way of traversing back to this from another function

Comment: I added some more code in my example, is pretty much the idea I have.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will try this out